# Angle between two points in Cartesian coordinate system C++

Tags: transformations, c++

I'm trying to rotate a rectangle so that it faces another rectangle in a spiral.

Im using the Bullet pyhics library and freeglut for the 3d application, for anyone interested https://github.com/damorton/bullet-dominos

[image]

```
float x = 0;
float z = 0;
float angle = 0.0f;
int a = 2, b = 2;
float previousX = 0.0f;
float previousZ = 0.0f;

for (int i = 4; i < maxPoints; i++)
{
    angle = 0.1 * i;
    x = (a + b * angle) * cos(angle);
    z = (a + b * angle) * sin(angle);

    GameObject* temp = CreateGameObject(x, 0, z);

    float newAngle = atan2(previousZ - z, previousX - x) * 180 / PI;
    temp->setRotationYaw(newAngle);

    previousX = x;
    previousZ = z;
}
```

You can see from the top view that the rectangles are not pointing towards the previous rectangles position.

[image]

EDIT: After trying the below code

```
float x = 0;
float z = 0;
float angle = 0.0f;
int a = 2, b = 2;
float previousX = 0.0f;
float previousZ = 0.0f;

for (int i = 0; i < maxPoints; i++)
{
    angle = 0.1 * i;
    x = (a + b * angle) * cos(angle);
    z = (a + b * angle) * sin(angle);

    GameObject* temp = CreateGameObject(x, 0, z);

    float dirX = -(a + b * angle) * sin(angle) + b * cos(angle);
    float dirZ = (a + b * angle) * cos(angle) + b * sin(angle);
    float newAngle = atan2(dirZ, dirX) * 180 / PI;
    temp->setRotationYaw(newAngle);

    previousX = x;
    previousZ = z;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Console output:

[image]

EDIT: Solution. Some things to note are that the result of `atan2()` was not converted to degrees using `atan2() * 180 / PI`. Also that I passed in `atan2(X, Z)` compared to `atan2(Z, X)` that is sometimes done for hysterical raisins http://www2.tcl.tk/10814.

```
// create spiral dominos
float x = 0;
float z = 0;
float angle = 0.0f;
int a = 2, b = 2;
float previousX = 0.0f;
float previousZ = 0.0f;

float dominoHeight = 2.0f;

for (int i = 2; i < maxPoints; i++)
{
    if (i % 30 == 0) dominoHeight++;

    angle = 0.15 * i;
    x = (a + b * angle) * cos(angle);
    z = (a + b * angle) * sin(angle);

    GameObject* temp = CreateGameObject(x, 0, z);

    float dirX = -(a + b * angle) * sin(angle) + (b * cos(angle));
    float dirZ = (a + b * angle) * cos(angle) + (b * sin(angle));
    float newAngle = atan2(dirX, dirZ);
    printf("dirX: %f - dirZ: %f - angle: %f\n", dirX, dirZ, newAngle);
    temp->setRotationYaw(newAngle);

    previousX = x;
    previousZ = z;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you could include in your post what libraries you use. Your using Unity right?

Comment: Using Bullet physics and freeglut

Comment: Not Unity https://github.com/damorton/bullet-dominos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parametric equation for a spiral is:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
    x &= &(a + b \theta) \times \cos(\theta)\\
    z &= &(a + b \theta) \times \sin(\theta)
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The direction on the spiral point is simply the derivative of the system with respect to $\theta$. Thus the direction is:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
 x_{dir} &=&-(a + b \theta) \times \sin(\theta) + b \times \cos(\theta)\\
 z_{dir} &=&(a + b \theta) \times \cos(\theta) + b \times \sin(\theta)
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Finally angle is is simply atan2 of the direction equation.

[image: Spiral]

**Image 1**: This is what I get when i plot squares at $(x, z)$ with direction $(x_{dir}, z_{dir})$

Mathematica [source](http://pastebin.com/ukNFUiPc) for image

Comment: I tried `float dirX = -(a + b * angle) * sin(angle) + b * cos(angle);` and `float dirZ = (a + b * angle) * cos(angle) + b * sin(angle);
` then `float newAngle = atan2(dirZ, dirX);` but this does not set the angle correctly.

Comment: I'm multiplying the result by 180 * Pi to convert to radians

Comment: Programming language is c++

Comment: Atan2 c++ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/

Comment: ill update the question with what I have so far can you have a look?

Comment: Ive just noticed that your circle is spiraling in the opposite direction to mine

Comment: @damorton It depends on how your csys is defined and from which side of the spiral you look from. These are arbitrary definitions. I just have a right handed coordinate system in a 2d space.

Comment: Turned out that the above was perfect, the problem was with the dimensions of each domino. Swapping the width and height values fix it :/ thanks @joojaa